# Ubuntu 14.04 server can't open port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

My case is quite specific. 
My client uses one of my services (https://example.com/service.php) and I generated for them SSL client certificate, which they use for http requests. but they have requirement that they can only use 1024 bit certificates (I had no problem generating it). but since my CA root certificate is 2048 bit requests fail. Now they want me to open port 4000 for them and require access via SSL cleint certificate. (If that makes any sense).

I run Ubuntu 14.04 on DigitalOcean VPS
I opened port 4000 with

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
```

I also allowed that port in **ufw** with

```
sudo ufw allow 4000
```

I also added  record to

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

I added it to **default-ssl.conf** because I want port 4000 to be accessible via https (https://example.com:4000/service.php)

```
<VirtualHost *:4000>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/client.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/client.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What Immediate problem I have is that when i try to telnet example.com:4000 it says that 4000 is closed. I need advice on trouble shooting.

Comment: "I run Ubuntu 14.04 on DigitalOcean VPS I opened port **4000** with sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport **80** -j ACCEPT". Are you sure about what you did?

Comment: well I copied here other command, i actually did open 4000 instead of 80. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What is still missing is the actual problem you are having. What is not working, and which symptoms do you see?

Comment: edited question to provide actual  problem

Comment: Check ``ss -tlnp`` for a process listening on port 4000. Check apache logs if there is no such process and especially (but not only) if there is also no process listening on port 80. Have you added ``Listen 4000`` to your apache config (outside and in front of the ``VirtualHost`` block), just to be sure?

Comment: Case was very strange. "Listen" commands were located in different file for some reason.

Comment: @JonasWielicki can you put it in answer so i could mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
Listen 4000
```

somewhere in your apache configuration. Otherwise, apache will not open a socket for that port.

Usually, these settings are apart from the `sites-enabled` or `sites-available` directories found on Ubuntu derivatives, for example in the main `httpd.conf`. A good place would probably be a separate file in `conf-available` and symlinking that into `conf-enabled`.